# Docker how to report phpunit test that run inside container

Tags: docker

I have a lamp application, and at the end of my Dockerfile I restart the apache

`CMD /user/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND`

And my question is, if I want to run a phpunit test inside the container, and how do I know if the test is passed or not ??

I thought of the following, is that a correct way to do it ?

For example, mount a volume from the host, and write the php unit test result to the mounted volume, so that I can know it is passing or not?

**If not, what would be the common way ( correct way ) of doing that ?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to do something like the following:

```
docker exec -it container-name phpunit ...
```

If you pipe the output to a location on the mounted volume you should be able to see the results there.